# react js run build wrong homepage

Tags: reactjs, github-pages

So i have published my react js app with GitHub pages, however, when I run the command npm run build, it appears the following:

> The project was built assuming it is hosted at /.
> You can control this with the homepage field in your package.json.

my package.json is the following

```
{
  "name": "sleepypower.github.io",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": false,
  "homepage": "https://sleepypower.github.io",
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.4.0",
    "react-multi-carousel": "^2.8.2",
    "react-particles": "^2.1.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "react-tsparticles": "^2.1.4",
    "tsparticles": "^2.1.4",
    "tsparticles-engine": "^2.1.3",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gh-pages": "^4.0.0"
  }
}
```

It should be that it is hosted at https://sleepypower.github.io

Comment: What is the problem exactly? `homepage` property doesn't support full urls.

Comment: I want to upload my react js website to my github page. The link is the following https://sleepypower.github.io . I believe it should say that the page is hosted there, but says is hosted at /

Comment: `npm run build` doesn't deploy your website, it just builds it into bundle. `homepage` is used for path resolving. If you want to deploy run `npm run deploy`

Comment: also note that refreshing your website while not being on the homepage result in a `404 not found`. This [repo](https://github.com/rafgraph/spa-github-pages) gives some instruction to resolve this problem.